# MPU6050 Power Management using Tiva C Direct Register Mode

Tags: mpu6050

Having no success getting the MPU6050 out of SLEEP mode. I understand that the SLEEP bit (bit 6) needs to be cleared, but reading the Power Management register after performing the clear returns 0x40. i.e bit 6 has not been cleared.

Yes this is for an assignment, and as such we are not allowed to make use of any libraries etc. My tutor was unable to assist and suggested I ask here.

My I2C setup is as follows

```
void I2C1_Setup(void)
{
//Setup I2C 1 on PORT A Pins 6, 7

// GPIO A 

SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO |= (1<<0); while ((SYSCTL_PRGPIO & (1<<0)) != (1<<0)) {}

GPIOA_AFSEL |= (1<<6)|(1<<7);
GPIOA_PCTL &= ~(0xFF<<24);
GPIOA_PCTL |= (3<<28)|(3<<24);
GPIOA_DEN |= (1<<6)|(1<<7);
GPIOA_ODR |= (1<<7);

// I2C 1

SYSCTL_RCGCI2C |= (1<<1); while ((SYSCTL_PRI2C & (1<<1)) != (1<<1)) {}
/*      
TPR = (System Clock/(2*(SCL_LP + SCL_HP)*SCL_CLK))-1;
TPR = (16MHz/(2*(6+4)*100000))-1;
TPR = 7
*/

I2C1_MCR = (1<<4);                  //master mode
I2C1_MTPR = (7<<0);                 //100Kbps   

//Disable SLEEP mode    
I2C1_MSA = 0xD0;                    // Set slave address and write mode
I2C1_MDR = 0x6B;                    // Power management register        
I2C1_MCS = 0x3;                     // start run mode
while ( !((I2C1_MCS & 1) != 0) ) {}
while ( (I2C1_MCS & 1) == 0 ) {}    // poll busy
I2C1_MDR = 0;
I2C1_MCS = 0x7;                     // stop start run mode
while ( !((I2C1_MCS & 1) != 0) ) {}
while ( (I2C1_MCS & 1) == 0 ) {}    // poll busy
}
```

To test the value of the power management register is use

```
    I2C1_MSA = 0xD0;                                // transmit mode
    I2C1_MDR = 0x6B;                                // register address
    I2C1_MCS = 3;                                   // start run mode
    while ( !((I2C1_MCS & 1) != 0) ) {}
    while ( (I2C1_MCS & 1) != 0 ) {}                // poll busy

    I2C1_MSA = 0xD1;                                // receive mode
    I2C1_MCS = 7;                                   // stop start run mode
    while ( !((I2C1_MCS & 1) != 0) ) {}
    while ( (I2C1_MCS & 1) != 0 ) {}                // poll busy
    int data;
    data = I2C1_MDR;
```

The return value for this is 0x40. When I perform the same steps to check the WHO_AM_I register (0x75) it is confirmed that the slave address is 0x68.

I know the MPU is functioning generally as we were able to get readings on an arduino using the simple sketch provided here (https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050)

I'm using the TM4C123GH6PM and keil uvision5.

Really not sure what is going wrong here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you completed your project. Could you share your codes about mpu6050 please. I need read gyro data from this sensor. Please help me. My email is ylmazedis@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

seems i used the wrong run mode when trying to send/rec. the data.
instead of using stop start run (0x7), needed to no resend the start command and just send stop run (0x5).

instead of

```
I2C1_MCS = 0x7;                     // stop start run mode
```

use

```
I2C1_MCS = 0x5;                     // stop run mode
```

Comment: hey! could you share your whole code with me please. yilmazedis@gmail.com